# Can ReactJS render components stored in a JavaScript String

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, reactjs

**Objective:**

Our system returns code in various places via AJAX/JSON. **I'm trying to render a ReactJS component that's stored in a JavaScript String.**

The desired result of the following script is to display `<h1>Hello World</h1>` once the AJAX call returns the ReactJS component.

---

**Example:**

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        )
    }
});

var Controller = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {mydata: "Hello There!"}
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.getJSON('ajax_controller.php', function(mydata) {
            self.setState({mydata: mydata});
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>{this.state.mydata}</div>
        )
    }
});
```

Here's the `ajax_controller.php` file.

```
echo json_encode(array('<HelloWorld></HelloWorld>'));
exit;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your render function in Controller is missing a return. I tried your example and it's worked only if the value myData is not string.

```
self.setState({mydata: <HelloWorld></HelloWorld>});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have updated the sample code and fixed the  render function in Controller. The reason I posted this question is to try to find a way to process the ReactJS components if the data IS a string though. I need to dynamically retrieve ReactJS components from the server via AJAX. To the best of my knowledge the JSON data returned from the server will always go into a string though.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any way your endpoint can return just the component name rather than the JSX you could use `React.createElement()`

Docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement

Example:

```
echo json_encode(array('HelloWorld'));
exit;
```

React code:

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        )
    }
});

var Controller = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {mydata: ""}
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        $.getJSON('ajax_controller.php', function(mydata) {
            this.setState({mydata: mydata});
        }.bind(this));
    },
    renderComponent: function(str) {
        return React.createElement(str);
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>{this.renderComponent(this.state.mydata)}</div>
        )
    }
});
```

(**side note:** I bound `this` to your AJAX request so you don't have to do the `var self = this;` line.  Personal preference.)